# OpenAPI definition not generating Scala properties

Tags: spring-boot, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm using the springdoc-openapi-ui plugin with spring-boot to generate an OpenAPI definition. It doens't seem to detect properties from Scala based objects. Java defined objects are working fine. Is there a way to fix this?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Controller:

```
case class OpenApiTest(a: String, b: String)

@RestController
class TestController {
  @GetMapping(path=Array("/open-api-test"))
  def openApiTest = OpenApiTest("a", "b")
}
```

Result of /v3/api-docs. Source is a Java class, OpenApiTest Scala:

```
"components": {
    "schemas": {
        "Source": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "path": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "OpenApiTest": {
            "type": "object"
        }
    }
}
```